# Variable assignment in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a js function

I want to assign a variable to a variable

my variable is in a forloop

I have two variables

ie;

```
var spcd_1= "http://www.colbridge.com";
var spcd_2 = "http://www.google.com";
```

below is my js function

```
function openNewWindow(spcd) {
//alert("hello");
var tt = spcd;
alert(tt);
var i=0;
var spcd_1= "http://www.colbridge.com";
var spcd_2 = "http://www.google.com";
for(i=1;i<3;i++)
{
var theurl="'spcd_'+i";
 popupWin = window.open(theurl,
 '_blank',
 'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable, dependent, width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0')

}
}
```

my problem is here

```
var theurl=spcd_+i;
```

I want to change `theurl` value to `spcd_1` and `spcd_2`

how to assign this correctly in the for loop

```
var theurl=spcd_+i;
```

can any one show me the correct method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to index an array, rather than trying to concatenate yourself up a variable name. Here's your code modified

```
function openNewWindow(spcd) {
    //alert("hello");
    var tt = spcd;
    alert(tt);
    var i=0;
    var spcds = [];
    spcds.push("http://www.colbridge.com");
    spcds.push("http://www.google.com");
    for(i=0;i<spcds.length;i++)
    {
        var theurl=spcds[i];
        popupWin = window.open(theurl,
        '_blank',
        'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable, dependent, width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0')

    }
}
```

Just for giggles, here's how you could keep using concatenation to get to your variable name. Objects in javascript can also be [associative arrays](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jarray2.htm), meaning you can use the array syntax to create and retrieve arbitrary properties

```
    var spcds = {};
    spcds['spcd_1'] = "http://www.colbridge.com";
    spcds['spcd_2'] = "http://www.google.com";
    //...
    var theurl = spcds['spcd_' + i];
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you should just put all the urls in an array, and loop thru it by index.

Javascript does not allow you to use a string to simulate a variable name, so create an array

```
var urls = ["link1","link2","link3"]; //Add as many urls you need here
```

and in the for loop, loop it

```
for (var i=0;i<urls.length;i++) {
//logic here
window.open(urls[i], '_blank',
 'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable, dependent, width=640, height=480')
//Do your thing
}
```

Comment: Actually, JavaScript does allow it.

Comment: and the second half of my answer (the just for giggles bit). Being able to use a string to access a property is mighty handy at times

Answer (score 5):

You should use an array, like this:

```
var urls = [ "http://www.colbridge.com", "http://www.google.com" ];

for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    window.open(urls[i], '_blank',
     'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable, dependent, width=640, height=480')
}
```

You should probably also read a book about Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet:

```
var my_var = "spcd_" + i;
```

Comment: This will simply assign the variable with the string "spcd_n", where n is the current number. That won't do what the asker wants.

Answer (score 0):

With a global variable, you could do

```
window["theurl_"+i];
```

because global variables are properties of window, and you can get at properties with either dot notation or bracket notation.

But don't do that. :-)

A good reason not to even try to do what you're doing is that JavaScript does not have block scoping, so putting vars anywhere but at the beginning of functions is likely to lead to confusion. You get into trouble sooner or later if you put variable declarations at the beginning of loops or conditional blocks.