# How to use a string as a variable name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a way to access a javascript variable using a string that contains the name of the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441532/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-javascript-variable-using-a-string-that-contains-the-n)
>   [JavaScript: Get local variable dynamicly by name string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920867/javascript-get-local-variable-dynamicly-by-name-string)

A simple code to illustrate my problem -

```
var chat_1 = "one";

var chat_2 = "two";

var id = "1";

var new = ?? variabalize( 'chat_' + id )
```

I want the variable new to be assigned the value of variable - chat_1 which is "one"

Comment: Variable variables are not good practice. Consider using an array instead.

Comment: Dup of [Is there a way to access a javascript variable using a string that contains the name of the variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441532/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-javascript-variable-using-a-string-that-contains-the-n), [Javascript using variable as array name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952457/javascript-using-variable-as-array-name), [How can I access local scope dynamically in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598878/how-can-i-access-local-scope-dynamically-in-javascript)

Comment: ... [Convert string to variable name in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript), [How to find JavaScript variable by its name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724857/how-to-find-javascript-variable-by-its-name), [how to use variable in a variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859709/how-to-use-variable-in-a-variable-name), [Javascript: Get access to local variable or variable in closure by its name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336508/javascript-get-access-to-local-variable-or-variable-in-closure-by-its-name)

Comment: ... [Javascript Variable Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592862/javascript-variable-variables), [“Variable” Variables in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript), [Variable assignment in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824095/variable-assignment-in-javascript), ... I give up.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Stop. Reorganise your code. If you want to select variables with a variable, then there has to be a logical grouping for them. Make it explicit.

```
var chat = {
    "1": "one",
    "2": "two"
};
var id = 1;
var new_is_a_keyword_and_cant_be_an_identifier = chat[id];
```

Comment: Hey thank you for replying, this looks live a very nice way of doing what I wanted. Also how do I add more "keys"/variables to this main chat variable?

Answer (score 6):

This is not a good practice, but you can do it as follows:

```
var i=1;
//window['name' + i] will now access the variable
```

Source: http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/archive/2007/06/14/variable_variables_in_javascri

Comment: +1 But I would emphasis **NOT GOOD PRACTICE**. Most of the time code like this is a result of coming from certain "other" languages... It must be pointed out this only works on *"global variables"* and will not work for variables defined within a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the global `window` object, assuming these are not defined inside a function:

```
var new = window['chat_' + id];
```

Comment: They are locally scoped variables. That won't work inside a function.

Comment: @Quentin They *may* be locally scoped (and the second statement holds). However, the question is vague on this and it will work for "global variables".

Comment: +1 for answering the question.  Providing warnings and context is fine, but I _hate_ it when people give lectures instead of answering the question.