# Alternative to eval when using an id in a function

Tags: javascript, circletype

I know that there are plenty of questions on "alternatives to eval" but so far I haven't found something corresponding to my case. I am using `[CircleType.js](https://github.com/peterhry/CircleType). Basically, in my case, the user provides a string corresponding to a part of the id of the element that has the circletype effect. Then, I paste a prefix to that string. After that, I need to use this string to destroy the circletype effect.

This is what I have:

```
function(id) {
   var newid = "circletype" + id;
   var newid2 = eval(newid);
   newid2.destroy();
 }
```

This is working, but I saw that `eval()` is "evil" and quite controversial. Therefore, I tried some stuff, such as:

```
function(id) {
   var newid = {"fullid": "circletype" + id};
   newid[fullid].destroy();
 }
```

to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6160166/11598948) but no success. Is there an alternative to `eval()` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is exactly like doing this :  `("circleType" + id).destroy()`.

In fact what you need to do is keep a reference of your CircleType instance and access it by a key. JavaScript allows you to create object literals and access its properties by using keys following this syntax:

```
var value = myObject['key'];
```

This is what the answer you mentioned tried to explain.

In your case you can implement something like this:

```
var circleTypes = {
    'circletypeId1': new CircleType('myElement1'), 
    'circletypeId2': new CircleType('myElement1')
};

function(id) {
   //Here Id should be equal to 'Id1' or 'Id2'
   circleTypes["circletype" + id].destroy();
}
```